# Unable to get .net Socket Status connected/disconnect to remote in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

Socket programming, ASP.Net C#, VS2008

I am trying to determine whether the status of remote(client) is connected or disconnected on every 5 second through timer control. Whenever I start the server first time I getting  the socket status is connected=true. But next time I getting  socket status is null.

Note: I am Accessing a Socket status from class to Aspx  page through creating object of a class.

This is my code:

Aspx page:

```
 protected void Timer1_Tick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Communication obj=new communication();
bool Rexits=obj.listen();
if(Rexits)
Response.write("Remote is On");
else
Response.write("Remote is Off");
}
**************************************************************************
Communication class:

Socket  listener=new Socket();
Socket connection;
  public bool listen()
        {
        listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,  

SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        bool RemoteExits = false;
        try
        {

            if (connection== null)
            {
                listener.Bind(endPoint);
                listener.Listen(pendingConnectionQueueSize);
                listener.BeginAccept(AcceptConnection, null);
                RemoteExits = IsConnected(connection);

            }
            return  RemoteExits;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            a = IsConnected(connection);
            return  RemoteExits;
         }
    }

//callback method

 protected void AcceptConnection(IAsyncResult res)
    {


       // Make sure listener doesn't go null on us.
        lock (this)
        {
           connection = listener.EndAccept(res);
           listener.BeginAccept(AcceptConnection, null);
        }

        // Close the connection if there are no handlers to accept it!
        if (Connected == null)
        {
            connection.Close();

        }
        else
        {
          TcpServer tc=new TcpServer();
           Clifton.TcpLib.ConnectionState cs=new    

Clifton.TcpLib.ConnectionState(connection,cs);
            OnConnected(new TcpServerEventArgs(cs));
        }
    }
//Poll Mehod
 public static bool IsConnected(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {

            bool connected = !(client.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) &&     

client.Available == 0);
            return connected;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you debug this code? What happens on the second run - does listen() throw an exception (i.e. run catch block)? Which statement in try block threw it? BTW, what's the purpose of a = IsConnected(connection) in the catch block?

Comment: @Miroslav Bajtoš Thank you for reply.
Yes I debugged this code.First time I am getting value in the connection variable(i.e.connection=System.Net.Sockets.Socket)On second time I am getting socket null(i.e connection=nulll)

IsConnected is in the catch block .If listen method throws the exception I called the poll method to check socket is connected or disconnected.

Comment: Could solve this  Using Non-Blockable socket with Poll method, it works only in debug mode. Problem is whenever I debug the code it showing correct remote is On or Off but whenever I run the code without debug it  always shows remote is off